# Micro strip antenna radiation pattern

Tags: microstrip

I'm designing a PCB micro strip antenna, 433.92MHz. I'm new to this and wonder, where does the antenna "start" radiating? I am trying to design the perfect length 1/4 wave for 433.92MHz (172.7233465 mm), so it would be helpful to know where the length should be calculated from. Is it where I "open" the ground plane (restrict copper pour)? Or also somewhere during the trace leading up to the antenna (depending on how wide the track and/or the spacing to the ground plane maybe)?
For the calculation, I am adding all the segments (straight lines on TOP layer, 3 segment S-shape on BOT layer). Should I add the 25 pcs 1.6mm through the PCB for every hole too?

Any hints on via stitching around the trace and/or the square?

[image: TOP+BOT layer]
[image: BOT layer]

Comment: This is a coil, not a dipole, so it will require different modeling IIRC. If anything, for ease of modelling, the top and bottom should be symmetric: straight point-to-point traces, top row of vias offset half pitch vs the bottom row of vias. Make it look like a string of W's, not a string of N's :) It being tucked in a corner doesn't help either. For ease of analysis, the antenna should be in a symmetric environment, i.e. sticking out from a ground plane, in the middle of the plane's edge. I'd make a PCB with the antenna longer than needed, then check it on a VNA and trim to size :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll make it into W instead. So I should increase the copper pour restrict rectangle?
Where approx. do I start measuring the length from?

Comment: Your "micro strip antenna" is definitely not [microstrip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip) by any conventional definition, and I'm not even sure it qualifies as an antenna, despite your intentions. The minimal loop area of your flattened spiral is going to interact only weakly with external H fields, and the closeness of the ground plane means it's also going to have only weak interaction with external E fields as well. What's the theoretical basis for this design?